# Merging multiple pdfs using py2PDF2 results in duplicates of a single pdf

Tags: python, pandas, pdf

I am trying to cycle through individual 1095 documents and merge them into a single pdf file. The documents are individually named last + ', ' + first + .pdf.

```
writer = PdfWriter()
for row in df_dict:
    print(row['Last Name'], row['First Name'])
    reader = PdfReader(path5 + '\\' + row['Last Name'] + ', ' + row['First Name'] + '.pdf')
    writer.append(reader)

with open(path5 + '\\2021_1095.pdf', "wb") as output_stream:
    writer.write(output_stream)
```

The result is X duplicates of Y pdf. X depending on the amount of pdfs and Y is the last pdf appended. I have tried using merge instead of append with no luck. I have also tried appending them as I fill them out individually with no luck either.

Answer (score 0):

So if you just want to merge all the PDFs in a folder, into one PDF, you could do it with mupypdf like this:-

```
import fitz
from pathlib import Path

directory = r'folder_path'
result = fitz.open()

files = Path(directory).glob('*.pdf')
for pdf in files:
    with fitz.open(pdf) as mfile:
        result.insert_pdf(mfile)
    
result.save(r'result.pdf')
```

This script is given some robustness by glob to catch only PDF files.